# django UpdateView widget_tweaks 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and developing a small app in which i have to update a Project Model. I am using django builtin UpdateView to update the details of a project already saved. I am also using widget_tweaks to render fields with custom bootstrap classes for styling. When i run this code it shows **str object has no attribute 'as_widget** Error. I think the form fields are going to the template as a string not as an object and render_field tag of **widget tweak** is unable to render it, but i don't know why it is going as a string?. I only want to update certain fields of the model. that's why I've used "fields" in UpdateView. But I also tried form_class just to check but that didn't work either. I've been stuck on this bug for two days. Any help will be appreciated.

Following is the project Model

```
class Project(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20 , unique=True)
    startDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    endDate = models.DateField()
    sourceOfProject = models.CharField(default='Website',  verbose_name='Project Source',max_length=20 , choices=(('Website' , 'Website'),('Client','Client')))  # website or client etc
    sourceName = models.CharField(default='' , verbose_name='Source Name' , max_length=20)
    paymentType = models.CharField(default='Fixed' , verbose_name='Payment Type', max_length=20 , choices=(('Hourly','Hourly'),('Fixed','Fixed')))  # If True then hourly else fixed
    ProjectPaymentAmount = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Amount')  # this amount is according to hourlyPayment==True or False
    is_Active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    projectSeverity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, choices=SEVERITY_CHOICES)
    hubstaffName = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True , default='')
    hoursToWork = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    def __str__(self):
        return "Project: {}".format(self.name)
```

Here is the view

```
class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ('hubstaffName','endDate', 'hoursToWork' ,'paymentType','ProjectPaymentAmount','sourceOfProject','sourceName',)
    #form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = "Administration/Manage-Projects.html"
    context_object_name = 'project_form' #name of the context object in the template
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pid'
```

following is the urls part.

```
path('edit-Project/<int:pid>',ProjectUpdateView.as_view(),name='editProject')
```

On this button click it post this form to 'Administration:editProject' view where I am using Update View.

```
<form action="{% url 'Administration:editProject' pid %}" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button id="EditProject" type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary mx-3 my-2" >Edit this Project</button>
                    </form>
```

Following is the edit template I am using to edit Project.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}



    <div class="container py-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto col-sm-6">
                    <!-- form user info -->
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="mb-0">Add Project</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <form method="post" class="form" role="form">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.name.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        {% render_field project_form.name class="form-control" %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.startDate.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="input-group date col-lg-9" data-provide="datepicker">
                                        {% render_field project_form.startDate class="form-control" %}
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.endDate.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="input-group date col-lg-9" data-provide="datepicker">
                                        {% render_field project_form.endDate class="form-control" %}
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.sourceOfProject.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        {% render_field project_form.sourceOfProject class="form-control" %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.sourceName.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        {% render_field project_form.sourceName class="form-control" %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.paymentType.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        {% render_field project_form.paymentType class="form-control" %}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label form-control-label">{{ project_form.ProjectPaymentAmount.label }}</label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                                        {% render_field project_form.ProjectPaymentAmount class="form-control" %}
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>


                                    </div>

                                        <div>

                                            </div>




                                        <div>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="save_home" type="submit">Save and Return</button>
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" name="save_another" type="submit">Save and Add Another</button>
                                        </div>
                            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here the ModelForm

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Project
            fields = ('name' , 'startDate' ,'endDate' , 'sourceOfProject','sourceName','paymentType','ProjectPaymentAmount','hoursToWork' )
            widgets = {'startDate':forms.SelectDateWidget(), 'endDate':forms.SelectDateWidget(),  'sourceOfProject':forms.Select()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `form_class = ProjectForm` in your `UpdateView`, where `ProjectForm` should be defined in `forms.py` for `Project` model. Than you would render your fields in templates as shown below.

```
Manage-Projects.html

{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

views.py

class ProjectUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = "Administration/Manage-Projects.html"
    context_object_name = "project"

forms.py

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Project
            fields = ('name' , 'startDate' ,'endDate' , 'sourceOfProject','sourceName','paymentType','ProjectPaymentAmount','hoursToWork' )
            widgets = {'startDate':forms.SelectDateWidget(), 'endDate':forms.SelectDateWidget(),  'sourceOfProject':forms.Select()}
```

The problem may also be in your Edit button, which you implemented as form. Do it like shown bellow using anchor tag and sending project.pk to url.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Administration:editProject' project.pk %}">Edit</a>
```

You can than remove pk_url_kwargs in your UpdateView and update url.

```
path('edit-Project/<int:pk>',ProjectUpdateView.as_view(),name='editProject')
```

Comment: I want to update only a certain fields of Project Model thats why I have used fields = ('hubstaffName','endDate', 'hoursToWork'. i also tried  with form_class=ProjectForm but it did'nt work. Moreover, my ProjectForm is already in forms.py i have updated the question with the code

Comment: But your form is not in your template, unless you define form_class in your view. There is nothing wrong with your definition of the ProjectForm.

Comment: I've defined form_class=Project in my view but that did not work either

Comment: It doesn't work using {% render_field form.startDate %} only in the template? I believe this should work considering your code

Comment: now it says 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'as_widget' when i only used form.startDate

Comment: And if you comment out fields in ProjectUpdateView?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I believe that this setup should definitely work, since I'm using the same one with another models and forms of course and its working. The only thing left that could cause errors are than the widgets you are using to override the defaults.